# undefined method `stringify_keys' for "create":String in ruby on rails again

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am getting an error

```
Started POST "/actions" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-10-29 15:04:01 +0600
Processing by ActionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"lfHYF3EQn1/lMReK3alX3NsGa4wSMejC/0fEeoAFYUY=", "commit"=>"Create Action"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `stringify_keys' for "create":String):
  app/controllers/actions_controller.rb:43:in `new'
  app/controllers/actions_controller.rb:43:in `create'
```

This code is totally generated by Rails, and i do not understand why it doesnt work

Here is model

```
class Action < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :user_id
end
```

Here is controller part

```
# GET /actions/new
# GET /actions/new.json
def new
  @action = Action.new

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @action }
  end
end

def create
  @action = Action.new(params[:action]) # here we get an error !

  respond_to do |format|
    if @action.save
      format.html { redirect_to @action, notice: 'Action was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @action, status: :created, location: @action }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @action.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

And here is the form code

```
<%= form_for(@action) do |f| %>
  <% if @action.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@action.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this action from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @action.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :user_id %><br />
    <%= f.number_field :user_id %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

When i press post, firebug shows this request parameters

```
utf8:✓
authenticity_token:lfHYF3EQn1/lMReK3alX3NsGa4wSMejC/0fEeoAFYUY=
action[name]:sdf
action[user_id]:23
commit:Create Action
```

if i understand correctly this must work and rails must turn action[name] and action[user_id] into hash table and place it into parameters[:action], then Action.new get this hash table as parameter. What is wrong ?

Comment: This error does not occure when my model does not have user_id field

Comment: i dont understand where it comes from too.

Comment: see below link for you solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10262576/undefined-method-stringify-keys-in-messages-controller

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, I know. You have a name clash.

`action` is a reserved name. Along with `controller`, `id` and maybe others. Use another name for your form.

When you post to `/actions/create`, then `params[:controller]` should be 'posts' and `params[:action]` should be 'create'. These params are assigned by Rails.

Comment: This helped, thanks! And where can i find all forbidden names and, maybe, another tricky tips for rails ?

Comment: Read books, man, read books. I recommend this one: [Agile Web Development with Rails (4th edition)](http://pragprog.com/book/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails).

Answer (score 0):

in your params you get params[:controller] = controller_name and params[:action] = action_name

In your case you are creating Action abject from action_name and not the params for object action. Try to use different name in params for object params.